# message.edit() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: discord.py

I'm migrating a discord bot to the new discord.py api, there's a part of editing messages, and its giving me that error..

```py
output = "new text"

await message.edit(output)
```

[Doc](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message)

am I reading the docs wrong? sry not a python literate, just helping a friend

Comment: I fixed it by message.edit(content=output)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation states that there are multiple fields which can be specified. In your case, you need to have `content=output` for the message to be edited.
Hope that helps!